# Labeling terminals and junctions in a BJT

Tags: schematics

The following schematic (sorry for the poor picture quality) was part of a question which asked to calculate \$\alpha\$, \$\beta\$ and \$V_C\$ for the given circuit.

[image: schematic of a BJT circuit]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fikN5R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I assumed the base current to be the current through the \$100\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor and obtained the answer. However, why is this the base current? More specifically, what does the line with an empty circle (the terminal symbol) really represent? My understanding is, it is simply used to represent the label the voltage at junction/node. Is this correct? Or, is the terminal part of a bigger circuit. If so, shouldn't the base current be obtained by apply the current rule at that junction?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: your hunch is correct ... it is the input for a signal that comes from a previous stage, whatever that may be

Comment: It's explicitly a node label, but it's also supposed to imply that a signal can enter there from the left. So it's not strictly ***just*** a node label. It carries an implication of a ground-referenced input signal line.

Comment: @jonk so, as far as solving the question is concerned, the lack of information regarding an input means that it is simply a node label?
Thanks.

Comment: @abhijeetviswa Which could just as well not be labeled at all, then. But yes, that's a valid statement.

Answer (score 1):

> what does the line with an empty circle (the terminal symbol) really
>   represent? My understanding is, it is simply used to represent the
>   label the voltage at junction/node. Is this correct?

They are just **tapping points or nodes**. I think them like an option to connect or insert a wire. it can be input (\$V_B\$) or output (\$V_C\$). It is just a representation to tell that one can either connect an input or a load or even simply a measuring device (DMM for example).